# My Apache rewrite rule does't work as my wish

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a site shop.example.com.
I want to make a rewriterule to Achieve like this:
Browser typing shop.example.com ----> /shop/index.php(server side)
and I write the rule like this:

```
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^shop.example.com [NC] 
RewriteRule ^$ shop/index.php
```

and it does not work,the Browser show nothing.
When I change the rule like this:

```
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^shop.example.com [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ssssssssss $ shop/index.php
```

It does work when Browser typing shop.example.com/ssssssssss ----> /shop/index.php
WHY?What should I do?
Please tell me! thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try:

```
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^shop\.example\.com$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^/?$ /shop/index.php [L]
```

Comment: I get the real reason and solve it in another way...and Still thank you.

Comment: You should post your solution for the benefit of SO users.